# wp8 hiding the keyboard on selectionchanged event

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, show-hide, autocompletebox

In my windows phone 8 application i am trying to hide the keyboard when the user selects in item from my autocompletebox.

I have tried to set the focus to another item and the page itself but the keyboard is still out
Any idea or other way to do so?

Answer (score 2):

```
Windows.UI.ViewManagement.InputPane.GetForCurrentView().TryHide();
```

or disable the TextBox and reenable it:

```
MyTextBox.IsEnabled = false;
MyTextBox.IsEnabled = true;
```

Comment: this is for wp 8.1 and above.
wp8 don't have TryHide method

Comment: Hmm, WP8 seems to have no direct way for that, added a workaround to my answer.

Comment: i have also tried this not so long ago, it did not help :/
and i'm using an autocompletebox not a textbox, and also not on keydown etc event but on selectionchanged.
all the "examples" are usually referring textbox and enter keys...